# Find node clicked on jsTree click event to expand or collapse

Tags: jquery, jstree, struts2-jquery

I have 4 levels of tree:

```
- Reg1
  -level 2
   -level 3
      -level 4
  +level 2
+Reg2
 level 2
    level 3
      level 4
  level 2
+Reg3
 level 2
    level 3
      level 4
  level 2
+Reg4
 level 2
    level 3
      level 4
  level 2
```

I have implemented this using using `struts2 jQuery JSTree` plugin using JSON data.

If I select any child node (e.g.: Reg1 --> Level 2 --> level 3 --> level 4), when I try to collapse or expand the tree node which contains the selected child (level 4), it triggers the click event.

When I expand/collapse on the other nodes which are in a different hierarchy (Reg 2 or Reg 3 or Reg 4), then it won't trigger the click event.

Is there anyway we can capture which element is clicked on the click event, so that if it's an image with INS tag then I can skip my logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action

Check out the `More widgets` -> `Tree` part

use the `onClickTopics` to catch the click event

Example

```
<sjt:tree 
            id="jsonTree" 
            href="%{treeDataUrl}"
            onClickTopics="treeClicked" 
        />
```

And you can get which element is clicked in the listen topic

```
$.subscribe('treeClicked', function(event, data) {
          var item = event.originalEvent.data.rslt.obj;
          alert('Clicked ID : ' + item.attr("id") + ' - Text ' + item.text());
    });
```